# How to avoid in Java simultaneous processing of unique combinations before persisting in database?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, locking

Maybe the obvious question but I cannot find an elegant solution for it

In a Spring Service initialized from a multithreaded Controller I process a request from a 3rd party that contains a combination of a confirmation code and a terminal number. Once we process  this request we persist this combination into the database and do not allow processing of this combination again.
The pseudo code is as follows:

```
protected void processAdmission(String confirmationCode, String terminalCode) 
throws AdmissionException {

    //Check availability in the database
    boolean isAvailable = checkDatabaseAvailability(confirmationCode, terminalCode);
    if (!isAvailable)
    {
        throw new AdmissionException();
    }
    saveInDatabase(confirmationCode, terminalCode);         
}
```

This unique combination is allowed only once to be processed; next time it should be an error because this combination is already in the database and we check the database .  What if this unique combination comes twice simultaneously?  The database protection will not help because the data are not in the database yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I created the new table and used select for update locking

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have the appropriate unique constraints in place and are using transactions:

- you do the work
- insert the values into the database
- commit the trasaction.

if the commit succeeds, all good.  if the commit throws a UniqueConstraintViolation, then the codes are already used and should be rejected (and the transaction will be rolled back so that any work you did is undone).

Answer (score 1):

Asumming your data is backed by a relational database, you can rely on your database.
If the pair (confirmationCode,terminalCode) is persisted in the same table, then a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint on the pair will preserve the uniqueness.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is very hard to prevent that on application level. Consider that you have more than one server up and running that receive the same combination of `terminal number` and `confirmation code`, you are screwed :-)

If there is just a single instance and a single JVM, you could use create a class with a `static HashSet` to save the number/code and a `synchronized` `static` method that adds and checks if the combination is already present. Although that should work, be aware of the possible disadvantages of the `synchronized` keyword in your particular environment.

Here an example where the `combination` is the concatenated string of `number` and `code`

```
public CombinationValidator {
  private static HashSet<String> combinations;

  public static synchronized boolean addAndCheck(String combination) {
      if (combinations.contains(combination)) {
          return false;
      } else {
          combinations.add(combination);
          return true;
      }        
   }
}
```

In the end, it is your database that needs to take care of that. Depending on your DBMS you would need to define unique key constraints. Then wait for the database to tell you if the insert has been successful. If so, continue to process the request. If not, throw the `AdmissionException`.